# Unable to get JNDI Datasource in JBoss 7.1

Tags: java, jboss7.x, datasource, jndi

I am trying to obtain a reference of a DataSource from JBoss 7.1, however I keep getting the below exception trace.

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: SpecOpsDB -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.SpecOpsDB
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:97)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:177)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.handleServerMessage(Protocol.java:124)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingServerV1$MessageReciever$1.run(RemoteNamingServerV1.java:70)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Now the configuration used are as follows:

**standalone.xml**

```
<datasources>
    <datasource pool-name="SpecOpsDB" jndi-name="java:/SpecOpsDB"
        enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spec_ops_schema</connection-url>
        <driver>com.mysql</driver>
        <pool>
            <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
            <prefill>true</prefill>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>root</user-name>
            <password>root</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
            <datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource</datasource-class>
        </driver>
    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

**module.xml**

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">  
  <resources>  
    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar"/>  
  </resources>  
  <dependencies>  
    <module name="javax.api"/>  
  </dependencies>  
</module>
```

**java code**

```
DataSource jBossDataSource = null;
try {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
    props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
    props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "admin");
    props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
    Context ctxt = new javax.naming.InitialContext(props);
    log.debug("Context Initialized");
    Object lookup = ctxt.lookup("java:/SpecOpsDB");
    jBossDataSource = (javax.sql.DataSource) lookup;
    log.info("Got JBoss DataSource");
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Jboss Console log** shows that the datasource is bound

```
11:01:09,105 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/SpecOpsDB]
```

I have even tested from JBoss Console UI and its working fine.

Any points that I have missed?

Comment: Are hou trying to do this lookup from within the server or from outside?

Comment: yes it is from a standalone java main method.

If I run it similar code in a servlet (without the properties object), it works perfectly.

Comment: You need the jboss jndi client jars in your classpath.

Comment: Thanks for the input, can you please point out which jars?? Also if there are missing jars,  shouldn't there be a ClassNotFoundException???

Comment: Try JBOSS_HOME/bin/client/jboss-client-7.1.x.Final.jar.